# Change the default width of a VuetifyJS DataTable cell

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I'm using the [VuetifyJS Data Table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#introduction) and I need to move the entries of each header cell as close as possible to each other.
I tried to add a *width* to each header but that didn't work - it seems there is a predefined width one can't go below.

Update: This is how it should look like - the margin between each row should be fixed at 10px:
[image]

Here is a CodePen [example](https://%20https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejEpKZ?&editors=101).

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="headerCell" slot-scope="props">
        <v-tooltip bottom>
          <span slot="activator">
            {{ props.header.text }}
          </span>
          <span>
            {{ props.header.text }}
          </span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </template>
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

How to get them close together?

Comment: What do you mean `width` doesn't work? It should be string e.g. `width:"10%"` or `width:"10"`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add another empty header and set `width` of every column to min value(1%), except empty to make it fill all free space. Also you need to add empty `td` to table body template to make grey row dividers visible.

See codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKXwOR

Comment: Thanks but the space between each column is still the same. I need the columns to be much closer together. How to do that?

Comment: In my example table tries to fill as few space as possible, if you want columns to be much closer then there is only one way to decrease padding of `th` and `td` elements (`table.v-table tbody td` and `table.v-table thead th` selectors). I updated answer codepen

Answer (score 51):

You can set width with header like below

```
headers: [
  { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', value: 'name', width: '20%'},
  { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', width: '50%' },
  { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
  { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs', width: '200px' },
],
```

Comment: this is the straightforward answer

Comment: I think while using header slot , this might not work.

Comment: love this answer

Answer (score 7):

Just add   (width,align) in your header

```
 <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
 </v-data-table>
```

header looks like

```
 header:[ {
        text: 'Dessert ',
          align: 'center',<------------to align left/center/right/
          value: 'name',
          width: "1%"//<-------------------asign width/
        },
   ]
```

Vuetify header options:

```
{
  text: string
  value: string
  align: 'left' | 'center' | 'right'
  sortable: boolean
  class: string[] | string
  width: string
}
```

Comment: simple and effective

Answer (score 1):

You can play with CSS, override their classes. Try modifying `td`'s `width`

Here you have a code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjxPMJ

I have also aligned text to the left for td :`<td class="text-xs-left">`

Just play with the width value to get what you want, you can use percentages as well.

Comment: OP wants headers close to _each other_ afaiu (so width should be altered)?

Comment: @Traxo you are right, I misunderstand the question, but yes, he can play with td's width then

Comment: @V.Sambor I tried your CodePen and used different values but the problem still exists.  Here is my updated example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajyjLZ

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all elements in array defined in fixed width such as "100px" don't work fine.
At least, one element of them should be defined in relative width like "10%".