# How to set <v-data-table> columns to fit its content width?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to set `v-data-table` columns to fit its content width ?

```
    <v-data-table
      style="background: transparent"
      dense
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      disable-pagination
      hide-default-footer
      no-data-text="No data available"
    >
      <!-- Titles -->
      <template
        v-slot:item.title="{ item }"
      >
        <div class="text-primary">
          {{ item.title }}
        </div>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527489/change-the-default-width-of-a-vuetifyjs-datatable-cell